# satisfying boolean n variable DNF formula

Tags: np-complete, satisfiability, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I have an n variable boolean DNF formula and an input set,z consisting of n-tuples. Each tuple consists of truth/false assignment to n variable.
the number of tuples in Z is not fixed, obviously <= 2^n.
Example: 
Lets assume, i have 2input DNF formula F(a,b) = a'b+ab'. Z={11,00,01}. I want to determine if any of these 3 input in Z satisfies F(a,b).
Again size Z is not fixed and worst case is 2^n input combination.
I want to prove whether this problem is NPC or P.I tried with boolean formula satisfiability but Z content is not fixed. So, they  are not exactly the same problem and I know general DNF formula satisfiability is in P. any suggestion, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in P.  Using the naive algorithm of just trying each input against each disjunction in Z, the runtime grows linearly with the size of Z and linearly with the size of F.  There's no exponential growth in runtime with the size of the problem, therefore the problem remains in P.